# What is the difference between **kwargs and dict in Python 3.2?

Tags: python, syntax, dictionary, arguments

It seems that many aspects of python are just duplicates of functionality.  Is there some difference beyond the redundancy I am seeing in kwargs and dict within Python?

Comment: `**kwargs` implicitly creates *a* `dict` object (named by `kwargs`) loaded with keys and values. This is not a duplicate functionality.

Comment: Expand on "many aspects". What other areas are duplicate functionality?

Answer (score 20):

There is a difference in argument unpacking (where many people use `kwargs`) and passing `dict` as one of the arguments:

- Using argument unpacking:

  ```py
  # Prepare function
  def test(**kwargs):
      return kwargs

  # Invoke function
  >>> test(a=10, b=20)
  {'a':10,'b':20}
  ```
- Passing a dict as an argument:

  ```py
  # Prepare function
  def test(my_dict):
      return my_dict

  # Invoke function
  >>> test(dict(a=10, b=20))
  {'a':10,'b':20}
  ```

The differences are mostly:

- readability (you can simply pass keyword arguments even if they weren't explicitly defined),
- flexibility (you can support some keyword arguments explicitly and the rest using `**kwargs`),
- argument unpacking helps you avoid unexpected changes to the object "containing" the arguments (which is less important, as Python in general assumes developers know what they are doing, which is a different topic),

Comment: With unpacking, the keys need to be valid identifiers

Comment: @gnibbler: You are right, +1. I totally missed that. As an example I would give `test({0: 10, '0': 20})` (which will return `{0: 10, '0': 20}`), that is hard to replace with argument unpacking.

Answer (score 7):

It is right that in most cases you can just interchange dicts and **kwargs.

For example:

```
my_dict = {'a': 5, 'b': 6}
def printer1(adict):
    return adict
def printer2(**kwargs):
    return kwargs

#evaluate:
>>> printer1(my_dict)
{'a': 5, 'b': 6}
>>> printer2(**my_dict)
{'a': 5, 'b': 6}
```

However with kwargs you have more flexibility if you combine it with other arguments:

```
def printer3(a, b=0, **kwargs):
    return a,b,kwargs

#evaluate
>>> printer3(**my_dict)
(5, 6, {})
```