# How To Check If A Key in **kwargs Exists?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, keyword-argument

Python 3.2.3. There were some ideas [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390126/pythonic-way-to-check-if-something-exists), which work on regular var's, but it seems **kwargs play by different rules... so why doesn't this work and how can I check to see if a key in **kwargs exists?

```
if kwargs['errormessage']:
    print("It exists")
```

I also think this should work, but it doesn't --

```
if errormessage in kwargs:
    print("yeah it's here")
```

I'm guessing because kwargs is iterable? Do I have to iterate through it just to check if a particular key is there?

Comment: There is no special rules. You just forgot the quotes.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

You want

```
if 'errormessage' in kwargs:
    print("found it")
```

To get the value of `errormessage`

```
if 'errormessage' in kwargs:
    print("errormessage equals " + kwargs.get("errormessage"))
```

In this way, `kwargs` is just another `dict`.  Your first example, `if kwargs['errormessage']`, means "get the value associated with the key "errormessage" in kwargs, and then check its bool value".  So if there's no such key, you'll get a `KeyError`.

Your second example, `if errormessage in kwargs:`, means "if `kwargs` contains the element named by "`errormessage`", and unless "`errormessage`" is the name of a variable, you'll get a `NameError`.

I should mention that dictionaries also have a method `.get()` which accepts a default parameter (itself defaulting to `None`), so that `kwargs.get("errormessage")` returns the value if that key exists and `None` otherwise (similarly `kwargs.get("errormessage", 17)` does what you might think it does).  When you don't care about the difference between the key existing and having `None` as a value or the key not existing, this can be handy.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation! Always good for python newcomers to get some background info and further examples of what is possible and what isn't. In that spirit: I think, `kwargs.get("errormessage", 17)` might return its value or `17` if errormessage doesn't exist - but I'm not sure. Is that correct?

Comment: Ah yes it does. Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098549/proper-way-to-use-kwargs-in-python). Thanks... just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 35):

DSM's and Tadeck's answers answer your question directly.

In my scripts I often use the convenient `dict.pop()` to deal with optional, and additional arguments. Here's an example of a simple `print()` wrapper:

```
def my_print(*args, **kwargs):
    prefix = kwargs.pop('prefix', '')
    print(prefix, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then:

```
>>> my_print('eggs')
 eggs
>>> my_print('eggs', prefix='spam')
spam eggs
```

As you can see, if `prefix` is not contained in `kwargs`, then the default `''` (empty string) is being stored in the local `prefix` variable. If it is given, then its value is being used.

This is generally a compact and readable recipe for writing wrappers for any kind of function: Always just pass-through arguments you don't understand, and don't even know if they exist. If you always pass through `*args` and `**kwargs` you make your code slower, and requires a bit more typing, but if interfaces of the called function (in this case `print`) changes, you don't need to change your code. This approach reduces development time while supporting all interface changes.

Comment: Thanks for showing how to assign a default value to `prefix`.

Comment: I really love the pass through behavior when wrapping functions -- it makes this technique particularly robust in the face of future updates to wrapped functions.

Answer (score 15):

It is just this:

```py
if 'errormessage' in kwargs:
    print("yeah it's here")
```

You need to check, if the key is in the dictionary. The syntax for that is `some_key in some_dict` (where `some_key` is something hashable, not necessarily a string).

The ideas you have linked ([these ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390126/pythonic-way-to-check-if-something-exists)) contained examples for checking if specific key existed in dictionaries returned by `locals()` and `globals()`. Your example is similar, because you are checking existence of specific key in `kwargs` dictionary (the dictionary containing keyword arguments).

Comment: To clarify: isn't `if some_key in kwargs:` more like `if some_key in some_dict.keys():`? In other words, isn't kwargs more like an unpacked dictionary?

Comment: Oh wait! you have a related answer which clarifies things quite a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491027/what-is-the-difference-between-kwargs-and-dict-in-python-3-2

Answer (score 6):

One way is to add it by yourself!  How?  By merging `kwargs` with a bunch of defaults. This won't be appropriate on all occasions, for example, if the keys are not known to you in advance. However, if they are, here is a simple example:

```
import sys

def myfunc(**kwargs):
    args = {'country':'England','town':'London',
            'currency':'Pound', 'language':'English'}

    diff = set(kwargs.keys()) - set(args.keys())
    if diff:
        print("Invalid args:",tuple(diff),file=sys.stderr)
        return

    args.update(kwargs)            
    print(args)
```

The defaults are set in the dictionary `args`, which includes all the keys we are expecting.  We first check to see if there are any unexpected keys in kwargs.  Then we update `args` with `kwargs` which will overwrite any new values that the user has set.  We don't need to test if a key exists, we now use `args` as our argument dictionary and have no further need of `kwargs`.

Answer (score 2):

You can discover those things easily by yourself:

```
def hello(*args, **kwargs):
    print kwargs
    print type(kwargs)
    print dir(kwargs)

hello(what="world")
```

Comment: Remove the "easy" and then it's a better answer. If it was easy for everybody, then we wouldn't need this site. Finding the `in` operator in itself is not easy if you've never programmed and/or are new to Python. It's only being hinted at in the `dict.get()` and `dict.setdefault()` help.

Answer (score 1):

```
if kwarg.__len__() != 0:
    print(kwarg)
```