# Simplify `if 'foo' in kwargs and kwargs['foo'] is True:`

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Is it possible to simplify the boolean check of a `kwargs` option?

For example in `foo` I have to check lots of options:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
   if 'foo' in kwargs and kwargs['foo'] is True:
      do_something()
   if 'bar' in kwargs and kwargs['bar'] is True:
      do_something_else()
   ...
```

One possible workaroud is to hide some complexity by adding more complexity...

```
def parse_kwargs(kwords, **kwargs):
   keywords = {}
   for kw in kwords:
      keywords[kw] = True if kw in kwargs and kwargs['kw'] is True else False
   return keywords
```

Then in my main function:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
   kw = parse_kwargs(**kwargs)

   if kw['foo']:
      do_something()
   if kw['bar']:
      do_something_else()
   ...
```

I would like to know if I can use a simpler method less boilerplate...

Comment: `if kwargs.get('foo'):`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399803/how-to-check-if-a-key-in-kwargs-exists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) is useful to avoid the `KeyError` when accessing a non-existent key:

```
if kwargs.get('foo'):
```

Or

```
if kwargs.get('foo', False):
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: The default value that `.get()` returns is `None`, so `kwargs.get('foo', False)` is really not required in this situation.

Comment: But do everyone a favor and just write `if kwargs.get('foo'):`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
   keywords = {'foo': do_foo_something,
               'bar': do_bar_something,
               'frug': do_frug_someting,
               ...}
   for k in keywords:
      if kwargs.get(k, False):
         keywords[k]()

def do_foo_something():
   do stuff

def do_bar_something():
   do stuff

def do_frug_something():
   do stuff
```

Comment: Hmmm... Useful technique to simplify the code. Nice work! :D

Comment: This is a good answer to this very question, but I was actually trying to avoid `KeyError` as [shx2](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2096752/shx2) found it.

Comment: Gotcha. I incorporated shx2's get() suggestion after I saw his answer. I thought you were after some way to manage all the 'do somethings'.

Answer (score 1):

The way to check for a value that might not be set is with `get()`, which returns `None` on missing keys instead of raising an error. But you should also change the `is True` part:

1. A boolean test comes out true if you just check the value itself; so it's simpler (and proper python style) to write

   if kwargs.get("foo"): 
       ...
2. `is True` is not only redundant, but incorrect: `is` does not check for value equality, but for identity. Any non-zero value counts as true in python, but e.g. `1 is True` comes out as false! `1 == True` checks for "truthiness", and is what you should have used (if anything). Even if **this** function will only receive True booleans, it's a bad idea to burden your code with needlessly strong assumptions about what it will see.

Comment: what if you are explicitly looking for `True`? `if kwargs.get('foo')` is not the same as  `if kwargs.get('foo')  is True`. Saying it is wrong is like saying `if some_val is None` is  wrong

Comment: In that case, `is True` is indeed appropriate. What do you think are the odds of that in this case?

Comment: Re the edit to your comment:  I called it incorrect precisely because it is not the same.

Comment: it is all about context, only the OP knows what values are possible

Comment: I agree, only the OP knows. But the `None` case is not the same: `None` is "falsy" but is also a missing value, so checking against it reveals a specific intent. If someone was testing with `is False`, then I would have made the same warning. Yes, it's conceivable but unlikely that it is really intended.

Comment: I meant that sometimes you do want to check if something `is True`, we cannot say something is wrong without first knowing the context of how it is being used

Comment: @Padraic, I agree as far as that goes. But I'm pretty confident in my guess at the author's intent, and in _that_ context, "`is True`" is incorrect.