# Checking the truthfulness of a keyword argument passed to a function does not work as expected - why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, keyword-argument

I know [how to check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399803/how-to-check-if-a-key-in-kwargs-exists) if I key in **kwargs exists. Now I want to check the value of an argument passed to a function.

```
def examplefunc(x,y,**kwargs):

    print(kwargs['extraarg'])
    if 'extraarg' in kwargs == True:
        print(kwargs['extraarg'])
        print("This is not printed")
    
    if 'extraarg' in kwargs: print("This is printed")
    
examplefunc(3,2,extraarg=True)
```

Output:

> True
>
> This is printed

Why isn't `This is not printed` printed? `'extraarg' in kwargs` is false. So why is it proceeding to print `This is printed`?

---

I also tried to replace the line `if 'extraarg' in kwargs == True` with `if 'extraarg' == True:`, but the output still lacks `This is not printed`.

Comment: chaining operator comparisons... try without `==True` or like this `if '(extraarg' in kwargs) == True`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you mean try something like `if ('extraarg' in kwargs)==True`?

Comment: yes, typo when parenthisizing my expr but yes. but just drop `==True` which is just redundant and you never have the issue!

Answer (score -1):

```
def examplefunc(x,y,**kwargs):

    print(kwargs['extraarg'])
    if ('extraarg' in kwargs)==True
        print(kwargs['extraarg'])
        print("This is not printed")

    if 'extraarg' in kwargs: print("This is printed")



if __name__ == "__main__":

    examplefunc(3,2,extraarg=True)
```

### output:

```
True
True
This is not printed
This is printed
```

Comment: this isn't the question

Comment: well, the code does not check that extraarg is True or False

Comment: @zabop  oh yeah right. I added the check for extraarg == True

Comment: I find it better to use if ('extraarg' in kwargs)==True suggested in the comments on the Q, but otherwise it works, thanks

Comment: It works because you're not chaining operators! This answer does not explain your issue, it just provides a different solution. @Jean-FrançoisFabre pointed you to the right direction in his comment!

Comment: yep, @Jean-FrançoisFabre's comment is answering my question!